# problem using identity theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am completely stuck in the following problem:

let f be holomorphic function on the unit disk $\{z:|z|\lt 1\}$ in the complex plane.which of the following is/are necessarily true?

**(a)** if for each positive integer $n$ we have $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n^2}$,then $f(z)=z^2$ on the unit disc.

**(b)** if for each positive integer $n$ we have $f(1-\frac{1}{n})=(1-\frac{1}{n})^2$,then $f(z)=z^2$ on the unit disc.

**(c)** $f$ cannot satisfy $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ for each positive integer $n$

**(d)** $f$ cannot satisfy $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n+1}$ for each positive integer n

what I thought in this problem is the following:

in the first part,by identity theorem we can say that $f(z)=z^2,\forall$z in the unit disc.

but,in the second part ,if we choose $g(z)=z^2$ then,$f(1-\frac{1}{n})=g(1-\frac{1}{n})$ but,the limit point ,i.e, $1$ is not in the unit disc.so,**in this case,we cannot use identity theorem to conclude whether $f(z)=z^2$ on the unit disk or not** .so,what procedure can we follow in this case???also,explain the options (c) and (d).

please answer in detail..

thanks a lot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For (D)** , Consider , $\displaystyle g(z)=f(z)-\frac{z}{z+1}$. Then , $g(1/n)=0$and $\{1/n\}$ has a limit point $0\in \mathbb D$. So, $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{z}{z+1}$ , which is analytic in $\{z:|z|<1\}$. So (D) is FALSE.

**For (C)** , put $\frac{1}{n}=z$. Then , $f(z)=z(-1)^{1/z}$ , which is NOT analytic at $z=0$. So (C) is TRUE.

**For (B)** , consider the function $\displaystyle f(z)=z^2+\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{1-z}\right)$ , which is analytic in $\{|z|<1\}$ satisfying your condition.

Answer (score 3):

(B) is the hard one.  Consider the function
$$f(z) = z^2 \cos \left( \frac{2\pi}{1-z} \right) $$

$f(z)$ is analytic on the (open) unit disk, and obeys 
$$f(1-\frac{1}{n})=(1-\frac{1}{n})^2$$
for each positive integer $n$, so (B) is false by this counterexample.